# I need to add a Username in the body based on received access-token from the user

Tags: wso2, wso2-micro-integrator

Does WSO2 (Integration Studio) has any solution to detect Username based on access-token code ??

The users are authorized to send their requests based on Oauth2. So every time they send my a access-token in Header (instead of username and password). however, to process their requests, I have to send the "Username" in Body of service toward a End-point.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such feature available in WSO2 to achieve what you need. The best option is to write a [Custom Handler](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/develop/customizations/creating-synapse-handlers/) to add the details you need to the request.